# How to get data from tables selected by reference from information_schema with some criteria in table name

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to get data like count or distinct from tables matching criteria in information_schema

```
SELECT 
    count(A.searchstring) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        table_name 
     FROM 
        information_schema.tables 
     WHERE 
        table_name LIKE 'wozsearch_200716_%') A;
```

There are 100's tables which have same structure but with different tables names, and I want to get the distinct values and row count of those tables.

`A.searchstring` is a column name in each table matching with table_name on the condition `LIKE 'wozsearch_200716_%'`.

From multiple table I can query total rows using:

```
SELECT sum(TABLE_ROWS)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'wozsearch_200716_%'
```

But I want to find out:

```
SELECT distinct searchstring FROM  table_name LIKE 'wozsearch_200716_%'
```

Error I receive:

> ```
> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.searchstring' in 'field list'
> ```

I have also tried using stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getdistinctrEs`(pattern char(50))
BEGIN
 DECLARE vtable_name TEXT;
        DECLARE getTempRecords CURSOR FOR SELECT a.`table_name` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables a WHERE a.`table_name` LIKE pattern;
    open getTempRecords;
    c1:LOOP 
    FETCH getTempRecords INTO vtable_name;
  
    set @query=concat("SELECT distinct searchstring FROM ",vtable_name);
    prepare st from @query;
   execute st;
    END LOOP c1;
       
    close getTempRecords;
END
```

getting result in individual hundred of tabs and mysql stucks and i have to restart workbench

Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: There isn't neither an A table nor an A alias in your query. And any column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is named `searchstring`. Maybe you copy and paste this piece of code?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "dynamic SQL".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count null values of table from information\_schema tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151855/count-null-values-of-table-from-information-schema-tables)

Comment: i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The stored procedure will produce for every table a separate result set.

You could `INSERT` The result of the `SELECT` into a temporary table, so that you have only one table as result:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE `getdistinctrEs`(IN pattern varchar(50), IN searchstring varchar(50))
BEGIN
 DECLARE vtable_name TEXT;
        DECLARE getTempRecords CURSOR FOR SELECT a.`table_name` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables a WHERE a.`table_name` LIKE pattern;
    open getTempRecords;
    c1:LOOP 
        FETCH getTempRecords INTO vtable_name;
  
        SET @query=concat("SELECT distinct ",searchstring," FROM ",vtable_name);
        PREPARE st from @query;
        EXECUTE st;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
    END LOOP c1;
       
    close getTempRecords;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure to build the SQL and insert the table name into that string.  Then "execute" it.